# Question about question about advacado

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[image: In case the image doesn't appear, this is the body of the question: Hello I have quetions how does juice an avocado I have try for thirtee minut and no juic. I try alredy. thank.]

This question has [historical significance](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8335/53917), but **it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site**, just as said on locked questions. Does it deserve to be undeleted and locked for good?

Comment: "This question has historical significance." No it doesn't.

Comment: What about link to the question?

Comment: @Qwertiy The question is deleted.

Comment: @zyabin101, anyway, starting from some rep it becomes visible by direct link.

Comment: When I saw this, I literally laughed for a minute and downvoted

Comment: AFAIK, It's more of a chat meme than anything else.... so no

Comment: I like how the "question about question about avocado" has more downvotes than the question about avocado.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

[image: No]

Seriously though, historical locks are for questions that were on topic once, but became off topic due to a change in the site's scope. That's not the case here.

Also, undeleting the question would send the message that this kind of prank is acceptable. That's also not the case; the user (sock) who posted that question was deleted for spamming the site.

And all the chatter about avocados *really* needs to stop...

Comment: `+1` for the gif. And because I agree with the answer, but *mostly* because of the gif.

Comment: Can we undelete and lock it to make it show up on suggested dupes? I recently closed/downvoted/flagged/commented on yet another copy of this question.

Comment: @NoOneIsHere As I said in my answer, it doesn't meet the requirements for a historical lock. Just flag it for moderator attention, and we'll remove it and deal with the poster.

Comment: @Dennis there isn't other lock types?

Comment: @NoOneIsHere Yes, but none that fits here. The closest one would be *content dispute*, but there's nothing to dispute here. Seriously, we don't need a dupe target for something that is not on topic, not a question, but pretty much vandalism. You couldn't close it as duplicate anyway; the original question would have to get an answer with a positive score first.